# Why does pandas.DataFrame.from_dict not support all orient of pandas.DataFrame.to_dict?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Why [`DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html#pandas-dataframe-from-dict) support only two orient?

> As per document
>   [`DataFrame.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html?#pandas-dataframe-to-dict) is supporting `orient: str {‘dict’, ‘list’, ‘series’, ‘split’, ‘records’, ‘index’}`
>   but [`DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html#pandas-dataframe-from-dict) support only two orient `orient{‘columns’, ‘index’}, default columns` (here `columns` similar to `list` of `to_dict`)

should not it be both way? (like `from_dict` to `to_dict` and `to_dict` to `from_dict`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The practical reason is probably because, *there isn't a need to*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({c: list(c) for c in 'ABC DEF'.split()})

# df
#   ABC DEF
# 0   A   D
# 1   B   E
# 2   C   F

orients = ['dict', 'list', 'series', 'records', 'index', 'split']
for o in orients:
    print(f'With orient {o}:')
    print(pd.DataFrame(df.to_dict(o)), '\n')
```

Observe what happens with just using the default `DataFrame` constructor:

```
With orient dict:
  ABC DEF
0   A   D
1   B   E
2   C   F

With orient list:
  ABC DEF
0   A   D
1   B   E
2   C   F

With orient series:
  ABC DEF
0   A   D
1   B   E
2   C   F

With orient records:
  ABC DEF
0   A   D
1   B   E
2   C   F

With orient index:
     0  1  2
ABC  A  B  C
DEF  D  E  F

With orient split:
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ValueError: arrays must all be same length
```

For all orients except `index` and `split`, these are already handled within the Constructor itself.  It's not that difficult to recreate with the last two as well:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(df.to_dict('index')).T
  ABC DEF
0   A   D
1   B   E
2   C   F

>>> pd.DataFrame(**df.to_dict('split'))
  ABC DEF
0   A   D
1   B   E
2   C   F
```

With the additional methods of `from_records` and `from_dict`, there are plenty of ways to interpret these input to reconstruct the `DataFrame`.  And in any case, is there a valid use case for passing data between `from_dict` and `to_dict` interchangeably, necessary enough to implement additional orients?

My gut feeling would be no.